# If an @ is not going to notify a user, there should not be auto-complete for a user handle

Tags: bug, user-interface, comment-replies, user-experience

This is a followup to a [question I asked on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363419/a-dot-prevents-a-mention-from-working). The gist of it is that I believed the sequence `.@` should notify a user, while as the accepted answer indicated, it should not.

What threw me off, and others as indicated by comments on that post, is that the auto-complete for a user handle (that one that pops up when we append characters to a `@`) is still getting activated.

So I could type `.@` and get suggestions for the handles of users who commented on the post. But naturally, they would not be notified. It's a slight case of false advertisement on the UI part. It happens across the network (I checked) and not restricted to a dot. Auto-completion pops up regardless of what appears before the `@`.

So I think this warrants this bug report. If the `@` is not going to be a user reply, there should not be auto-suggestions for user handles popping up.